# NestJS access Reponse anywhere

Tags: typescript, express, nestjs

Is it possible to access the Response Object from a service? You can access the Request from anywhere like this:

```js
import { Inject, Injectable, Scope } from '@nestjs/common';
import { REQUEST } from '@nestjs/core';

@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST })
export class ResponseService {
    constructor(@Inject(REQUEST) private readonly request: Request) {}
}
```

But is there a similar way for the Response or can I just create a new Response object?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that you have access to the request everywhere, is because it's already created. About response, when you call a service method from a controller, the response is not finalized and will be created based on the `return` value of the controller (which can be a service call or anything). Maybe if you can elaborate with more details we can provide more proper solution.

But you can access the response in **filters** if you have an exception.
See here for more info: https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters

Comment: So I could just create a new Response Object anywhere (to set the HTTP status etc..) and return it?

Comment: No, I'm afraid you can not do it directly from service. Because HTTP responses happen on the controller layer (based on it's return value)